# c# clase para gestionar distintos proveedores de BD

Tags: c#, sqlite

Tengo el siguiente código , esta clase donde defino la interface

```
namespace classBD.clases.connexiones
{

    public interface IConexion
    {
        void OpenConection();
        void CloseConnection();
        void ExecuteQueries(string Query);
        object ShowDataInGridView(string Query);
        DbDataReader DataReader(string Query);
        Boolean Ejecutar(string query, Dictionary<string,string> parametros);

    }


    public class ConnectionFactory
    {
       public static IConexion GetConnection()
       {
           string valconfig = "sqlite";
           if(valconfig == "sqlite")
               return new conexionSQlite();
           else
               return new conexionSQLServer();
       }
    }

}
```

Luego tengo una implementación para sqlServer y otra para Sqllite (pongo solo un trozo de código)

```
namespace classBD.clases.connexiones
{

    public class conexionSQlite : IConexion
    {
        SQLiteConnection conexionSQLite;


        public void OpenConection()
        {
            conexionSQLite = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                conexionSQLite.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            conexionSQLite.Close();
        }

    ...
    ...


        public Boolean Ejecutar(string query, Dictionary<string, string> parametros)
        {
            Boolean retorno = true;
            this.OpenConection();
            SQLiteCommand Comando = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexionSQLite);
            foreach (var p in parametros)
            {
                Comando.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            try
            {
                Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                retorno = false;
            }

            return retorno;
        }


    }
}
```

Luego tengo algo parecido para sql server.

Al ejecutar este código el error que recibo es este[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Falta algo de información en tu pregunta, pero imagino que lo que quieres es tener un diccionario con el nombre del parámetro y su valor, y añadirles a la coleccion de parámetros. Para eso, lo primero deberías usar el método `AddWithValue` en lugar de `Add` de la colección `Parameters`. Tu código deberia quedar asi:

```
foreach (var p in parametros)
{
     Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.Key, p.Value);
}
```

Para completar, el error que te da es porque no puedes añadir un `KeyValuePair` a la colección de parametros. Si quieres añadir solo el nombre del parametro para poner su valor a posteriori, tu código debería ser:

```
Comando.Parameters.Add(p.key,SqlDbType.VarChar); //Aqui debe ir el tipo que corresponda
```

Como entiendo que no quieres preocuparte de los tipos de los parámetros, la mejor solución en tu caso sea probablemente la primera usando `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estás haciendo esta parte del código:

```
SQLiteCommand Comando = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexionSQLite);
foreach (var p in parametros)
{
    Comando.Parameters.Add(p);
}
```

En concreto en el `.Add` deberás usar alguna de las sobrecargas que tenga, si mal no recuerdo una de las que te puede servir es la de pasarle un `new SQLiteParameter()` por lo que te quedaría el código así:

```
SQLiteCommand Comando = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexionSQLite);
foreach (var p in parametros)
{
    Comando.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(p.Key,p.Value));
}
```

Finalmente como consejo he visto que usas `var` para la definición temporal del `foreach`, te recomiendo que si sabes que tipo es uses el correcto ya que con esto prevendrás futuros errores.